# How to filter and sort the same table data with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, filter, state

I'm having an issue where upon loading the page I can either sort the table by the "name" column (ascending or descending) - - OR - - use a searchbar to filter through the names of the employees. My issue is that once I've sorted alphabetically, the search/filter no longer works.

I'm very new to React (I'm sure that's very obvious by my code) so please let me know if there's something obvious I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance!

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import API from "../utils/API"
import EmployeeRow from "./EmployeeRow"

class TableMain extends Component {
    state = {
        result: [],
        search: "",
        sortOrder: "descending"
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        API.search()
            .then(results => {
                console.log(results)
                this.setState({
                    result: results.data.results.map((res, i) => ({
                        image: res.picture.large,
                        firstName: res.name.first,
                        lastName: res.name.last,
                        phone: res.phone,
                        email: res.email,
                        dob: res.dob.date,
                        key: i
                    })
                    )
                })
            })
    };

    filterResults = (results) => {
        const value = this.state.search
        const finalResult = results.filter((employee) => {
            const lastName = employee.lastName.toLowerCase();
            const firstName = employee.firstName.toLowerCase()
            const fullName = firstName + " " + lastName

            if (fullName.includes(value)) {
                return employee
            }
        });

        return finalResult
    };

    sortResults = (event) => {
        const results = this.state.result
        // const id = event.target.id
        // if (id === 'name'){
        // } else if (id === 'phone'){
        // } else if (id === 'email'){
        // }
        if (this.state.sortOrder === "descending") {
            results.sort((a, b) => {
                if (a.firstName > b.firstName) {
                    return -1
                }
                return a.firstName > b.firstName ? 1 : 0
            }, 
            this.setState({ sortOrder: "ascending" }))
        } else if (this.state.sortOrder === "ascending") {
            results.sort((a, b) => {
                if (a.firstName < b.firstName) {
                    return -1
                }
                return a.firstName > b.firstName ? 1 : 0
            }, 
            this.setState({ sortOrder: "descending" }))
        }

        console.log("RESULTS: ", results)

        this.setState({
            sortedResults: results,
            isSorted: true
        })
    }

    onChange = e => {
        const value = e.target.value;
        if (!value) {
            this.setState({ isSearchEmpty: true });
        } else {
            this.setState({ search: e.target.value, isSearchEmpty: false });
        }
    }

    render() {
        // console.log("State", this.state)
        let employeeResults = this.state.result 

        if (this.state.isSearchEmpty) {
            employeeResults = this.state.result
        } else {
            employeeResults = this.filterResults(this.state.result)
        }

        if (this.state.isSorted) {
            employeeResults = this.state.sortedResults
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <input label="Search" onChange={this.onChange} />
                <div className="row">
                    <table style={{ width: "100%" }}>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Image</th>
                                <th style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} onClick={this.sortResults} id="name">Name</th>
                                <th id="phone">Phone</th>
                                <th id="email">Email</th>
                                <th id="dob">DOB</th>
                            </tr>
                            {[...employeeResults].map((item) =>
                                <EmployeeRow
                                    image={item.image}
                                    firstName={item.firstName}
                                    lastName={item.lastName}
                                    email={item.email}
                                    phone={item.phone}
                                    dob={item.dob}
                                    key={item.key}
                                />
                            )}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        )}
}


export default TableMain;
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is:

```js
    if (this.state.isSorted) {
      employeeResults = this.state.sortedResults;
    }
```

When you sort, you set `state.isSorted` to true, however you never set it back to false once you have finished.  When you then try to filter, you do the filter:

```js
    if (this.state.isSearchEmpty) {
      employeeResults = this.state.result;
    } else {
      employeeResults = this.filterResults(this.state.result);
    }

    if (this.state.isSorted) { // this is never reset after sorting.
      employeeResults = this.state.sortedResults;
    }
```

But as `this.state.isSorted` is still true, you use the values in `this.state.sortedResults` again.

---

> please let me know if there's something obvious I'm doing wrong

You are making this tricky for yourself, as you are filtering/sorting the same collection of data. That's why you need to perform the action in the render, as you are trying to maintain the original list for later usage.

If you seperate the list into two collections: original unmodified and a display list, you can always refer to the original list to perform filtering/sorting.

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    API.search().then(results => {
      const tableData = results.data.results.map((res, i) => ({
        image: res.picture.large,
        firstName: res.name.first,
        lastName: res.name.last,
        phone: res.phone,
        email: res.email,
        dob: res.dob.date,
        key: i
      }));

      this.setState({ originalResults: tableData, displayResults: tableData });
    });
  }
```

Then filtering can be done, as soon as the `onChange` occurs:

```js
  onChange = e => {
    const query = e.target.value;

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      displayResults:
        query.length > 0
          ? this.filterResults(query, prevState.originalResults)
          : prevState.originalResults
    }));
  };
```

and similarly for the sorting, which can be performed on the display-results rather than the whole which means you can now sort, filtered results.

I created an example here https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-cannon-d61z6

I stubbed out all the missing functionality.